# Eslint doesn't work in VScode, but work from terminal

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, eslint, monorepo

I have monorepository managed by rush (https://rushjs.io/)

The structure of code is:

[image]

As you see, there are two eslint configs and two directories `node_modules` (it is just symlink created by rush).

Eslint to back work perfectly.

But I have some troubles with eslint config to front. When I run it with 
`yarn eslint --ext .js --ext .jsx ./src` from directory `front`, it work.

But it doesn't work, when eslint has launched from vscode. In output I see:

```
Consider running eslint --debug /Users/oleg/Desktop/projects/hire/front/src/pages/config.js from a terminal to obtain a trace about the configuration files used.
[Error - 2:04:08 PM] 
Failed to load plugin 'react' declared in 'front/.eslintrc': Cannot find module 'eslint-plugin-react'
Require stack:
- /Users/oleg/Desktop/projects/hire/__placeholder__.js
Referenced from: /Users/oleg/Desktop/projects/hire/front/.eslintrc
Happened while validating /Users/oleg/Desktop/projects/hire/front/src/pages/config.js
This can happen for a couple of reasons:
1. The plugin name is spelled incorrectly in an ESLint configuration file (e.g. .eslintrc).
2. If ESLint is installed globally, then make sure 'eslint-plugin-react' is installed globally as well.
3. If ESLint is installed locally, then 'eslint-plugin-react' isn't installed correctly.
```

`eslint-plugin-react` is already installed and defined in front/package.json

Do you have any idea, why eslint can't work?

P.S Eslint config:

```
{
  "parser": "babel-eslint",
  "extends": [
    "airbnb",
    "plugin:react/recommended"
  ],
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "node": true,
    "jest": true,
    "es6": true
  },
  "plugins": [
    "react",
    "jsx-a11y"
  ],
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 6,
    "sourceType": "module",
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "jsx": true
    }
  },
  "rules": {
    "newline-before-return": "error",
    "newline-after-var": "error",
    "arrow-parens": [
      "error",
      "always"
    ],
    "arrow-body-style": [
      2,
      "as-needed"
    ],
    "comma-dangle": [
      2,
      "always-multiline"
    ],
    "import/imports-first": 0,
    "import/newline-after-import": 0,
    "import/no-extraneous-dependencies": 0,
    "import/no-named-as-default": 0,
    "import/no-unresolved": 2,
    "import/prefer-default-export": 0,
    "indent": [
      2,
      2,
      {
        "SwitchCase": 1
      }
    ],
    "max-len": 0,
    "newline-per-chained-call": 0,
    "no-confusing-arrow": 0,
    "no-console": 1,
    "no-use-before-define": 0,
    "prefer-template": 2,
    "class-methods-use-this": 0,
    "react/forbid-prop-types": 0,
    "react/jsx-first-prop-new-line": [
      2,
      "multiline"
    ],
    "react/jsx-no-target-blank": 0,
    "react/require-extension": 0,
    "react/self-closing-comp": 0,
    "react/display-name": 0,
    "require-yield": 0,
    "import/no-webpack-loader-syntax": 0,
    "react/prop-types": [
      0
    ]
  },
  "settings": {
    "babel-plugin-root-import": {
      "rootPathPrefix": "~/",
      "rootPathSuffix": "src/"
    }, 
    "import/resolver": {
      "webpack": {
        "config": "./webpack/webpack.prod.js"
      }
    }    
  },
  "globals": {
    "CONFIG": true
  }
}
```

Comment: I had a similar problem as the title of your question, and here was the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76351963/470749

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Add to workspace settings:

```
{
    "eslint.workingDirectories": [
        "back",
        "front"
    ]
}
```

and potentially:

```
{
    "eslint.workingDirectories": [
        { 
            "directory": "front", 
            "changeProcessCWD": true
        }
    ]
}
```

The problem is with where vscode/eslint looks for dependencies.

Comment: For those unfamiliar with how VSCode handles settings, @Mykybo's recommended additions should go into the Workspace Settings (JSON), as outlined here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings

Comment: After a whole lot of searching, (for about 6, 7 hours), your answer finally fixed my issue, so thank you.

Comment: To anyone fighting with this - the workindDirectories option also now supports `"eslint.workingDirectories": [{ "mode": "auto" }]` which could also work without you having to manually specify the directories

Answer (score 1):

Going to add ***"babel/next" not installed to here.*** so hopefully google picks this up.
eslint works fine in cli.
eslint complains in vscode on all import lines.

Have been going through loads of different recommendations and none of them have worked properly > adding and correctly configuring this file is the correct answer.

So for instance if you have a *website* folder add this.

```
"eslint.workingDirectories": [
      { "pattern": "website/*/" }
    ]
```