# VSCode no longer shows Eslint errors after I switched to Eslint flat config (although eslint still works in terminal)

Tags: visual-studio-code, next.js, eslint, typescript-eslint

I have Eslint working in a TypeScript Next.js project, but I want to switch to the new "flat config" approach that Eslint offers.

I created `/eslint.config.js` to look something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74819187/470749

### Part 1

How can I migrate the `extends: ['next/core-web-vitals'],` to the flat config, which doesn't support `extends`?

### Part 2

Other than missing 'next/core-web-vitals', if I run `eslint pages/*`, I see the errors that I expect.

But my VSCode no longer shows errors.

I see `"eslint.experimental.useFlatConfig": true,` in my VSC settings, and I've restarted VSC, but it still doesn't work.

How can I get the flat config to run automatically in VSC?

Comment: What version for VSC ESLint plugin are you using? You should also split this into two questions rather than two parts of one question.

Comment: Note to self: I was then having trouble getting VSC to honor Eslint on a totally separate computer and separate repo, and to solve _that_, I needed so unsync the VSC Eslint settings. I still haven't solved _this_ question.

Answer (score 4):

**Part 1**
extends syntax that was compatible with config files is not needed in the flat file config that is code - just import/require the plug-in as a normal lib.

**Part 2**
The vscode-eslint extension was slow to adopt the flat file config and I do not think it is fully supported yet (in the case of workspaces), but 2.4.0 supposedly works. I have not used this version but I did use the pre-release that it is based on.

**extra**
After multiple engineers burning lots of time on eslint's mess (not just the flat file config) we are moving away from eslint. Lots of gravity behind eslint but Id rather bare that cost than the hair-pulling insanity of eslint.

Comment: Hi Tom, out of interest, what are you moving to?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Part 2 isn't working even though I have 2.4.0. And I still don't know how to do Part 1. I think it's probably something with FlatCompat: https://eslint.org/blog/2022/08/new-config-system-part-2/#backwards-compatibility-utility

Answer (score 1):

I  had already seen in the terminal `TypeError: Could not find the rule "canonical/filename-match-exported".`, but I'd ignored it.

Seeing it again in ESLint Show Output Channel made me wonder whether VSC was aborting there and not bothering to run any more rules.

And that seems to be the case.

Once I removed `/* eslint-disable canonical/filename-match-exported */` from the files that had those comments, VSC started honoring my ESLint rules (even in tsx files).

It seems like a bug (or questionable design choice) that the VSC ESLint extension would fail in a nearly silent way if it can't find a rule definition.

Comment: This time, my problem was that I made incorrect assumptions about `unicorn/prevent-abbreviations`. It _was_ working. A good test is: `const res = 'res';
  console.log(res);` I still don't know why `y++` isn't getting caught by rule `no-plusplus`.

Answer (score 1):

if you are migrating to javascript config for eslint and working with vscode don't forget to enable flat config support in your vscode settings.
You can specify it in settings.json file like this:

```
"eslint.experimental.useFlatConfig": true
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT
I needed to add `"type": "module",` to `package.json` to get `export default [` to work.

---

The eslint instructions say to create the export using...
`export default [`

I had to keep it as...
`module.exports = [`
...for vscode to recognize the file.

And use `require()` for imports.